# Delete all the previous backup leaving last two of them

Tags: shell-script

I am taking backup of my linux server using an script. It uses the following code for naming system

```
# Create archive filename.
day=$(date +%A)
hostname=$(hostname -s)
archive_file="$hostname-$day.tgz"
```

I want to delete all the previous backup leaving last two of them. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just let your backup script delete the archive created the day before yesterday:

```
# Create archive filename.
day=$(date +%A)
hostname=$(hostname -s)
archive_file="$hostname-$day.tgz"

# Do backup
#...

# Delete old backup (assuming GNU date)
deleteday=$( date -d '2 days ago' +'%A' )
rm -f "$hostname-$deleteday.tgz"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
find ... -mtime +2 -exec rm {} \;
```

Or similar :)